# Some apps unexpectedly sorting "Aa" after "Z" (Danish Collation)

Tags: macos, internationalization, bbedit

This is on Ventura 13.5.2, a machine where I've migrated through many computers and versions of Mac OS X, so there could be some lingering cruft causing this problem.

To the best of my knowledge, I've only ever used en_US language/locale on my computer.

I noticed today that Quicken was sorting the names "Aaron" and "AARP" after the letter Z in my list of payees.  BBEdit was doing the same.  But a folders in the Finder were alphabetized correctly, and passing a list to `sort` in a Terminal window worked as well.

From the Wikipedia page on [Alphabetical Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order), I learned that:

"In the Danish and Norwegian alphabets, the same extra vowels as in Swedish (see below) are also present but in a different order and with different glyphs (..., X, Y, Z, Æ, Ø, Å). Also, "Aa" collates as an equivalent to "Å"."

My Terminal shows the following:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My "Language & Region" System Settings lists "English (US) -- Primary" as my only language, and "United States" as my Region.

What other methods can I use to get or set macOS's language/region?

Update:

I checked another account that I recently created on this computer, and it lists "English -- Primary" as the language (note the missing "(US)").  When I sort in BBEdit from that account, I get the correct order.

But I've been unable to get "English -- Primary" on my current account.  I switched to French and removed English entirely, rebooted, and when I tried to add "English" instead of "English (US)", it still added the "English (US)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shared this in a [TidBITS Talk post](https://talk.tidbits.com/t/macos-apps-unexpectedly-sorting-aa-after-z-danish-collation/25065?u=tomlogic) that helped me figure out the root cause.

I found that `AppleCollationOrder` in the `.GlobalPreferences.plist` file was set to `nb`, the locale for [Norwegian Bokmål](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/nb/index.html).

I also learned that the command-line `defaults` utility reads/writes that file.  So after executing the command `defaults delete -g AppleCollationOrder` and relaunching BBEdit, my sorts are working as expected!

I have no idea how or when I ended up setting the collation order to a non-English value, I'm just glad it's resolved.